# Using Groovy, how do I format an Oracle timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy, timestamp

I have the following code:

```
sql.eachRow(sqlQuery, ((pageNumber-1)*pageSize)+1, pageSize) { row ->
List<String> nextRow = new ArrayList<String>();
nextRow.add("$row.EVENT_TMSTP");
    ...
```

but what I get for the timestamp is:

```
oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@1d44e01
```

instead of:

```
12-SEP-13 10.55.00.392000000 AM
```

I've tried various ways to get the timestamp formatted, but none work.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Does `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP.stringValue()` not get the correctly formatted result.

Comment: it worked!  This is what i used nextRow.add("${row.EVENT_TMSTP.stringValue()}");  Put your input as an answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMP.html), you should just be able to call:

```
nextRow.add("${row.EVENT_TMSTP.stringValue()}");
```